# T-sql Inner Join erratic behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying a simple self join, but it's output is some what erratic.

My table (input) looks like this:

```
 ID  |   Value    
 1   |    val1   
 1   |    val2   
 1   |    val3  
 2   |    val4   
 2   |    val5   
 2   |    val6  
 2   |    val7
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
 ID 1  |   Value 1  | ID 2  |   Value 2  
 1     |    val1    | 2     |   val4   
 1     |    val2    | 2     |   val5  
 1     |    val3    | 2     |   val6  
 Null  |    Null    | 2     |   val7
```

My attempt at achieving this output has been the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    column1.ID,
    column1.value,
    column2.ID,
    column2.value
FROM table column1   
INNER JOIN table column2 ON column1.ID = 1 AND column2.ID = 2
```

This chunk of code returns the incorrect number of rows; the total number of rows I should get is 4 with a few a null values in the last. I don't get any null values but I do get some numbers which I don't know how are getting there. Additionally, if choose to display more fields from my table, the numbers of rows returned grows larger. I don't understand this behavior. Can Somebody please help me fix it? (and possibly tell me what I am doing wrong).

Comment: I find it **highly confusing** when you're using `column1` as a **table** alias..... it just violates the *Principle of Least Surprise*. If something is called **Column1**, I expect it to be a **column** - but **NOT** a table! And also: is your table really called `table` ?? If so, it's another really poorly chosen name ......

Comment: The actual table I am using is complicated and un-insightful for this problem, so I chose 'table' so people wouldn't get distracted by the name. You are right about me using poorly chosen aliases, but I am just doing what is required of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You separate both your data sets in different CTE or sub-queries and use ROW_NUMBER() function in the process to assign row numbers in order of value. In the end join the two on row number - but using FULL instead of INNER join so you can get null values on whatever side has fewer rows.

```
WITH CTE_1 AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS RN
    FROM dbo.table1
    WHERE ID = 1
)
, CTE_2 AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS RN
    FROM dbo.table1
    WHERE ID = 2
)
SELECT 
    c1.ID AS ID1 
  , c1.VALUE AS Value1
  , c2.ID AS ID2
  , c2.VALUE AS Value2
FROM CTE_1 c1
FULL JOIN CTE_2 c2 ON c1.RN = c2.RN
```

SQLFIddle is not working at the moment, I can't setup a demo, but here is sample table I have used:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Value] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'val1'),
    (1, 'val2'),
    (1, 'val3'),
    (2, 'val4'),
    (2, 'val5'),
    (2, 'val6'),
    (2, 'val7')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this effectively. There is no relationship between the rows on the left side and the right side of the join. A join needs a relationship; your `ON` condition doesn't specify a relationship between the two so you will see lots more rows than you intend.

If you are trying to use SQL to format your data for display, *DON'T*. Get your data, then format it in your client application.

Comment: +1: It can actually be done, but it's a total pointless pain-in-the-neck for exactly the reasons you site: there's nothing relational about it.  This is what presentation software (spreadsheets, report generators, etc.) is for.

Comment: Okay. However, if I impose the relationship on my on statement as:  '... ON column1.ID = column2.ID+1', it still doesn't work. Why do I still get more rows then intended. But I see your point, this is a really ineffective way of doing things.

Comment: @AmmarTareen Because without a relationship that limits your selection, it's effectively a `CROSS JOIN`: each row joining with every row.